# IntegrityError null value in column "name" of relation "tag" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I have created an API and am currently testing my post request with Postman. However, I keep getting this error.

**views.py**

```
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = TagSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(name=request.POST.get("name"),
                                       language=request.POST.get("language"))
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Tag
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'language')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    return Tag.objects.create(**validated_data)

  def to_representation(self, data):
    data = super().to_representation(data)
    return data
```

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
        return tag_data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name field in your tag model is not nullable. So it looks like you are trying to create a Tag model without a name value.

My guess is your request.POST is probably empty. Did you check it ? The recommanded way is to use request.data instead.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/

By the way, if you want to use serializer, you can do all the process calling its functions.
So, you are supposed to check if the serializer is valid by calling
`serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` and then create the object with `save()`. And if you want something more custom, you can override the `.save()` method of your serializer

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = TagSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save() # the result contains the tag instance
```

It may be also more efficient if you use CreateAPIView directly instead

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

ps: It can't see where you are going with `serializer.save(tag_input)`.

Comment: Ok, I have modified my code now (also above) but I keep getting the same error.